# Create UILabel on any view controller from a method

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a method that gets called if a video upload to Facebook has failed. If that method is called then I would like for a `UILabel` to briefly appear in any view controller that a user happens to be on at the time the upload fails.

Is this possible?

I asked a similar question earlier about a `UIAlertView`, but I realized that there are certain circumstances under which an alert could negatively impact user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this is many ways -

1) you can add `UILabel` to your applications main `Window`.

2) if you are using a `UINavigationController` then you get the instance of current `viewcontroller` and then can add `UILabel` to its view.

3) if you are using a `UITabBarController` in this case you can also get the instance of current `viewcontroller` by accessing `tabBarController`'s selected `viewcontroller.`

Answer (score 0):

this code Im posting below is from [HackBook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook) sample app from facebook. they done similar to what you want.

```
- (void)showMessage:(NSString *)message {
CGRect labelFrame = messageView.frame;
labelFrame.origin.y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - 20;
messageView.frame = labelFrame;
messageLabel.text = message;
messageView.hidden = NO;

// Use animation to show the message from the bottom then
// hide it.
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect labelFrame = messageView.frame;
                     labelFrame.origin.y -= labelFrame.size.height;
                     messageView.frame = labelFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                               delay:3.0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              CGRect labelFrame = messageView.frame;
                                              labelFrame.origin.y += messageView.frame.size.height;
                                             //    UIView *messageView; declared in header
                                              messageView.frame = labelFrame;
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              if (finished) {
                                                  messageView.hidden = YES;
                                                  messageLabel.text = @"";
                                              }
                                          }];
                     }
                 }];
 }
```